# How to avoid Java.util.IllegalStateException in the following code?

Tags: java, exception, collections, iterator, arraylist

I have a List of integer's with duplicate values in it. What I need to do is find the duplicate integers, add their value and then add the result to the list by removing the duplicates found. Here is what I am doing:

```
List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list1.add(2);
    list1.add(5);
    list1.add(3);
    list1.add(5);
    list1.add(4);

    List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Iterator<Integer> it = list1.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Integer int1 = it.next();
        if (list2.isEmpty()) {
            list2.add(int1);
            it.remove();
        } else {
            ListIterator<Integer> it2 = list2.listIterator();
            while (it2.hasNext()) {
                Integer int2 = it2.next(); 
                if (int2 != int1) {
                    it2.add(int1);
                    it.remove();// I get exception here

                } else {                        
                    it2.remove();
                    it.remove();
                    Integer newint = int1 + int2;
                    it2.add(newint);
                }                   
            }
        }
    }       
    for(Integer in : list2){
        System.out.println(in);
    }
```

Output should look like
    `2

     10

     3

     4`

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Just as a side comment, it's recommendable to refer to interfaces instead of concrete implementations (i.e. write List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are allowed to use a Map you could do something simple like this (incoming pseudocode):

```
create empty Map m
for each Integer x in list1 do
    if m does not contain key x 
        m.put(x, x)
    else
        m.put(x, m.get(x) + x)
    endif
done
```

Your result are the values of m (which is a Collection).

**Edit:** You said you have LatLng instead of Integers - I don't know LatLng but after a quick google I'd take a shot at the following, assuming that you want to "add" up your LatLng points:

```
create empty Map<LatLng, LatLng> m
for each LatLng x in list1 do
    if not m.containsKey(x) 
        m.put(x, x)
    else
        m.put(x, LatLng.newInstance(m.get(x).getLatitude() + x.getLatitude(),
                                    m.get(x).getLongitude() + x.getLongitude()))
    endif
done
```

The only problem I can see here is that this `m.containsKey(x)` depends on the correct implementation of `equals`, which I'm not sure after reading [this](http://gwt-google-apis.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/maps/1.0/com/google/gwt/maps/client/geom/LatLng.html#isEquals%28com.google.gwt.maps.client.geom.LatLng%29)

Comment: The thing is I cannot use Map, I am actually working with google maps and I have LatLng points instead of Integer, so when I as to get some thing on map with LatLng point it returns null :(

Comment: This is what I tried and it works after overwriting equals method.  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

As the other posters have said, you can't remove while iterating. Even though there are 'tricks', messing with a collection while iterating is a surefire way to get weird runtime bugs.

Anyway, you are working way too hard on the problem.

Here's a quick and dirty solution with a fraction of the code:

```
private List<Integer> sumAndUniqDuplicates(List<Integer> list) {
    LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer> lookup = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for (Integer value : list) {
        Integer prevValue = lookup.get(value);
        prevValue = (prevValue == null) ? 0 : prevValue;
        lookup.put(value, prevValue + value);
    }
    return new ArrayList<Integer>(lookup.values());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because you remove the same element twice. First time in `if(list2.isEmpty())` (because `list2` is empty in the beginning and immediately after that in the `else` body.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to overcome this issue ? Even if I dont remove first time, I mean in list2.isEmpty block, it still gives me the error.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation for the `remove` method:

> Removes from the underlying collection the last element returned by the iterator (optional operation). **This method can be called only once per call to next.**

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove the current element twice. You need to rethink your logic.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to achieve it?